# Angular 5 sanitize for json response

Tags: angular, sanitization, sanitize

I am working with angular 5, previously we have the project in angular js , now we are change it to angular 5.

I am using the already existing WebAPI responses,

for showing dynamic action menus ,
in response:i am getting some anchor tag like

`<a href="#" title="Recommend to" onclick="\&quot;fnShowMyRecommendedUsers('http://localhost:4200/MyReCommendedUsersParams/true/Contentid/34cac8bf-01a8-49d3-9251-a39eb94e2563/userid/1')\&quot;">Recommend to</a>`

and javascript function like

`javascript:fnAddItemtoMyLearning('ab63ea41-5eb6-4860-b477-cc50a70af5ba');`

so, i use DomSanitizer

and i tried as below

app.component.html

```
    [innerHtml]="course.ViewLink | safe:'html'" - showing html script in front end

href={{course.ViewLink | safe:'script'}} -- showing the action link but action is not working

ng-click="course.ViewLink | safe: 'script'" -- showing the action link noting happening 

(click)="course.ViewLink | safe: 'script'" -- showing error
```

i want to call method in app.component.ts like somefunction().

Need help hands, thanks .

Comment: Why are you trying to add your `ViewLink` to the `click` event?

Comment: @ArunRajR , i want call the method in .ts , so i tried it , please help me out how to call method using sanitize from html template.